# How to build libonion?

Tags: c, linux, build

I have tried to build onionlib from sources. I cannot use git on my Debian 8 workstation so I downloaded zip from the github. CMake fails at main CMakeLists.txt:28, 29, 30, etc. with error **string sub-command REGEX, mode REPLACE needs at least 6 arguments total to command**.

It seems that **ONION_VERSION** variable is empty. Tried to do git clone on other PC and then copied the whole folder including .git to the target workstation with the same result. Tried to execute .git-version-gen and got output '0.8.123.f6b9d' I also get an empty **-- Onion version is** during compilation so the version is undefined.

```
npa@NPA:~/workspace/TMOIP/onion$ sudo sh ./git-version-gen
0.8.123.f6b9d
npa@NPA:~/workspace/TMOIP/onion$ mkdir build
npa@NPA:~/workspace/TMOIP/onion$ cd build
npa@NPA:~/workspace/TMOIP/onion/build$ cmake ..
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 4.9.2
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 4.9.2
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:28 (string):
  string sub-command REGEX, mode REPLACE needs at least 6 arguments total to
  command.

CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:29 (string):
  string sub-command REGEX, mode REPLACE needs at least 6 arguments total to
  command.

CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:30 (string):
  string sub-command REGEX, mode REPLACE needs at least 6 arguments total to
  command.

-- Onion version is
-- Using epoll as poller
-- Could NOT find GnuTLS (missing:  GNUTLS_LIBRARY GNUTLS_INCLUDE_DIR) 
-- Could NOT find GCrypt, try to set the path to GCrypt root folder in the system variable GCRYPT_ROOT_DIR (missing:  GCRYPT_INCLUDE_DIR GCRYPT_LIBRARIES) 
Gnutls or gcrypt not found. SSL support is not compiled in.
-- Could NOT find PkgConfig (missing:  PKG_CONFIG_EXECUTABLE) 
SQLite session support is not compiled in.
-- hiredis client library not found.
Hiredis not found. Redis session support is not compiled in.
-- pthreads found. Threading support is compiled in.
-- Found LibXml2: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libxml2.so (found version "2.9.1")
-- WebDAV support is compiled in.
No PAM support.
-- Could NOT find ZLIB (missing:  ZLIB_LIBRARY ZLIB_INCLUDE_DIR) 
-- Could NOT find PNG (missing:  PNG_LIBRARY PNG_PNG_INCLUDE_DIR) 
libpng not found. No png support.
-- Could NOT find JPEG (missing:  JPEG_LIBRARY JPEG_INCLUDE_DIR) 
libjpeg not found. No jpeg support.
-- Could NOT find PkgConfig (missing:  PKG_CONFIG_EXECUTABLE) 
-- Found GC library: BOEHM_GC_LIBRARIES-NOTFOUND
-- Could NOT find Boehm_GC (missing:  BOEHM_GC_LIBRARIES BOEHM_GC_INCLUDE_DIR) 
-- NOT compiling Boehm GC examples
-- Could NOT find CURL (missing:  CURL_LIBRARY CURL_INCLUDE_DIR) 
curl not found. Some examples wil not be built.
-- Could NOT find PkgConfig (missing:  PKG_CONFIG_EXECUTABLE) 
-- Could NOT find SYSTEMD (missing:  SYSTEMD_INCLUDE_DIRS SYSTEMD_LIBRARIES) 
Systemd support is not compiled in. Install libsystemd-dev | systemd-devel
md2man-roff NOT found, NOT compiling manpages. Install it via 'gem install md2man'
-- Prepared for packaging
-- Compiling WebDAV support
-- Found include files 
CMake Error at src/onion/CMakeLists.txt:107 (SET_TARGET_PROPERTIES):
  set_target_properties called with incorrect number of arguments.

-- Found include files onion.hpp;dict.hpp;request.hpp;response.hpp;url.hpp;handler.hpp;extrahandlers.hpp;shortcuts.hpp;exceptions.hpp;listen_point.hpp;http.hpp;https.hpp;mime.hpp
CMake Error at src/bindings/cpp/CMakeLists.txt:10 (SET_TARGET_PROPERTIES):
  set_target_properties called with incorrect number of arguments.

CMake Warning at examples/CMakeLists.txt:9 (message):
  Oterm without authentication support! May be very unsecure.

CMake Warning at examples/CMakeLists.txt:14 (message):
  Some examples are disabled as you dont have PAM: otop, basic, fileserver.

-- jQuery at /usr/share/javascript/jquery/jquery.min.js
-- Using system provided jquery for oterm
-- Could NOT find ZLIB (missing:  ZLIB_LIBRARY ZLIB_INCLUDE_DIR) 
CMake Warning at examples/CMakeLists.txt:37 (message):
  Some examples are disabled as you dont have libpng: mandelbrot

-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/npa/workspace/TMOIP/onion/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that the problem was in CMake call of git-version-gen script. I was able to run it manually but it was not running correctly from the CMake because of some permissions setup of my workstation. The problem gone after it was corrected.